# Facebook Feed Dialog properties JSON object outputting both key and value

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

For Facebook Feed Dialogue:

```
properties: {"text":"Somestuff"},
```

outputs "text: Somestuff"

I only want to output "Somestuff"

Answer (score 0):

It seems

```
properties: {"text":"Somestuff"},
```

outputs "text: Somestuff"

If you want only "Somestuff"

```
properties: {" ":"Somestuff"},
```

will work.